# Which indexes should I create?

Tags: postgresql, index

I need assistance in which indexes to create on a table, and the best approach for querying it.
We use PostgreSQL.

Here’s the table:

```
create table myt (
    the_time timestamp, 
    oid int, 
    counter int, 
    other_counter decimal(8,2) 
);
```

The 'key' is the timestamp + oid.
We slice the table into 30 minutes periods.
The columns `counter` and `other_counter` are aggregated for this period.

Here’s a data sample from the table:

```
insert into myt 
values 
('2012/01/01 00:00', 1, 10, 2.5),
('2012/01/01 00:30', 1, 5, 1.5),
('2012/01/01 00:30', 2, 8, 13.5),
('2012/01/01 01:00', 1, 15, 4),
('2012/01/01 01:00', 2, 10, 2.25),
('2012/01/01 01:00', 3, 2, 4.5),
('2012/01/01 01:30', 1, 10, 3.75),
('2012/01/01 02:00', 2, 30, 1.5),
('2012/01/01 02:30', 3, 10, 22.5),

('2012/01/02 00:00', 1, 10, 34.5),
('2012/01/02 00:30', 1, 70, 1.25),
('2012/01/02 01:00', 1, 20, 12.0),

('2012/01/03 00:00', 2, 40, 50),
('2012/01/03 00:30', 2, 90, 10);
```

I need to query the table based on `the_time` and `oid` and sum the counters.

This is the basic query:

```
select
  date_trunc('day', the_time) as interv_start,
  date_trunc('day', the_time) + interval '1 day' as interv_end,
  sum(counter), 
  sum(other_counter)
from myt
where oid in (1, 2)
  and the_time >= date '2012/01/02'
group by date_trunc('day', the_time)
order by interv_start;
```

We’ll probably set time limit with `BETWEEN`.  Sometimes we’ll do `the_time` = … as well.

I would like to know which indexes to create.

I probably need this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON myt (the_time, oid);
```

However, do I need the following indexes?

```
create index time_trunc_Idx on myt (date_trunc('day', the_time));
create index oidIdx on myt (oid);
create index time_idx on myt (the_time);
```

Here are the execution plans results based on the different indexes:
For one index: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/01ae6/1/0

```
Sort  (cost=24.42..24.43 rows=1 width=26)
    Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, the_time))
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=24.40..24.41 rows=1 width=26)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on myt  (cost=7.55..24.36 rows=5 width=26)
                Recheck Cond: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
                Filter: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..7.55 rows=453 width=0)
                      Index Cond: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
```

And here with 4 indexes,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e34c7/1

```
Sort  (cost=19.08..19.09 rows=1 width=26)
    Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, the_time))
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19.06..19.07 rows=1 width=26)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on myt  (cost=8.41..19.02 rows=5 width=26)
                Recheck Cond: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
                Filter: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on oididx  (cost=0.00..8.41 rows=14 width=0)
                      Index Cond: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
```

I’d appreciate your inputs.

---

Edited:
Here are 3 explain options (no index, one index, four indexes)

No Index:

```
Sort  (cost=30.48..30.48 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=2 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, the_time))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=1
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=30.45..30.47 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.031..0.032 rows=2 loops=1)
         Group Key: date_trunc('day'::text, the_time)
         Buffers: shared hit=1
         ->  Seq Scan on myt  (cost=0.00..30.41 rows=5 width=26) (actual time=0.012..0.015 rows=5 loops=1)
               Filter: ((oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[])) AND (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 9
               Buffers: shared hit=1
```

One Index:

```
Sort  (cost=24.43..24.43 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.061..0.062 rows=2 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, the_time))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=8
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=24.40..24.42 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.040..0.042 rows=2 loops=1)
         Group Key: date_trunc('day'::text, the_time)
         Buffers: shared hit=5
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on myt2  (cost=7.55..24.36 rows=5 width=26) (actual time=0.020..0.024 rows=5 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
               Filter: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
               Heap Blocks: exact=1
               Buffers: shared hit=5
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..7.55 rows=453 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=5 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
                     Buffers: shared hit=4
```

Four Indexes:

```
Sort  (cost=19.09..19.09 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=2 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, the_time))
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19.06..19.08 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=2 loops=1)
         Group Key: date_trunc('day'::text, the_time)
         Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on myt3  (cost=8.41..19.02 rows=5 width=26) (actual time=0.029..0.032 rows=5 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
               Filter: (the_time >= '2012-01-02'::date)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 7
               Heap Blocks: exact=1
               Buffers: shared hit=3 dirtied=1
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on oididx  (cost=0.00..8.41 rows=14 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=12 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (oid = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
                     Buffers: shared hit=2
```

Comment: Something is wrong - in the first run (without the index) you get 2 rows, in the other two it's 0.  Otherwise, these timings show you don't really have anything to optimize.  Are there typical queries that return more rows?

Comment: Now I run the same query on the same data (very small amount of rows). I mistakenly didn't put data when testing with indexes. BTW, is there a difference in the order of conditions in the WHERE clause? thanks @dezso